# How to get JVM metrics with Finagle?

Tags: jvm, metrics, finagle

<strike>For the same application code</strike>, I get them to appear on machine A but not on B.
On machine B I still get many of the metrics mentioned in the Finagle docs, but not the [JVM ones](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/Metrics.html#jvm).

Is there any JVM setting, or another environment setting, that would enable/disable JVM metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`JvmStats.register(statsReceiver)`

---

Turns out I had a wrong assumption in: "the same application code is running on A and B."

My app would startup differently on machine B because it's running on a web container: it would skip the normal TwitterService startup lifecycle, which you get if you [extend `TwitterServer` with a `main()` method](https://twitter.github.io/twitter-server/).
Somewhere along this lifecycle `JvmStats.register` gets called. That's how machine A had JVM metrics. I finally managed to get them on B by adding that one line.